# Can Someone zip those up for me?

Tags: wi-fi

I deleted etc/wifi
          etc/dhcpcd from android system root/data

Now my wifi won't turn on..
Can someone zip those folders for Gionee P4 or other device with similiar firmware
I performed factory reset
            data + partition wipe

Or something that would fix my wifi

Answer (score 4):

Don't cast any further wipes. It looks like you don't know the insides of Android very well. It won't fix your recent problem right now but to prevent it from getting worse, remember:

## NEVER DELETE THINGS IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT THEY ARE!!!

For your actual problem: You shouldn't use files from another phone. Perform a clean flash of the ROM you use/you want to use. That is the safest route.